# AddCors is not working in asp.net 5.0. How do I enable it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, cors

So my problem is that I tried to enable the CORS, followed the tutorial and it is still not working. My startup.cs looks like this (I include methods to which I tried enabling CORS). Any help would be appreciated:

ConfigureServices method:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options=>options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder=>builder.AllowAnyOrigin()));
        services.AddControllers();
        services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(ApplicationDbContext), 
            new ApplicationDbContext(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))));
    }
```

And then I try to use cors in the Configure method.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

I use the newest .NET core version.

Error specifically is:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/cities' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this syntax and assign name to the policy

```
    services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigins", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));

        .......


            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigins");

            app.UseAuthorization();
```